# Error running a Python program with sklearn.cluster - "DLL load failed while importing _pairwise_distances_reduction"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dll, module, pip

I am running Windows 10, and I have Python installed.
When trying to run a Python program with the line `from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN` in it, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ._pairwise_distances_reduction import PairwiseDistancesArgKmin
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pairwise_distances_reduction: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried solving this by entering each of these in the command line (separately, not all at once) and checking whether or the program works:

- `pip install sklearn`
- `pip install scikit-learn`
- `pip uninstall scipy` then `pip install scipy`
- `pip uninstall numpy` then `pip install numpy`

I still get the same error when running the program. I'm having difficulty troubleshooting this, searching for "_pairwise_distances_reduction" returns no helpful results.
Is there something I'm supposed to install that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too, I installed Visual C++ Redistributable Runtimes libraries and it solved my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).